# How to connect a xp laptop with a vista laptop wirelessly?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, wireless-networking, lan

How can I connect a xp laptop with a vista laptop wirelessly.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [wireless ad-hoc network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) for them to communicate through.

Comment: Maybe you can give specific instructions?

Comment: There's a link to a **very** detailed guide at the bottom of that page: http://jamus.co.nz/techthought/2009/07/18/wireless-ad-hoc-networking/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than explain it here (which would make for a lot of dry typing), let me give you a link that should send you on your way:

[Making the Wireless Home Network Connection in Windows XP Without a Router](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/expert/bowman_02april08.mspx).

Answer (score 0):

• Turn on wifi

• Go to network connection (click Start -> Control Panel -> Network and Internet connection -> Network Connection)

• Right click on the wireless network connection, and then click Properties.

[image]

• Select the Wireless Networks tab -> click Advanced

[image]

• Select the Computer-to-computer (ad hoc) networks only

[image]

• Click Close, The display will return to the Wireless Network Properties Connnection

• In the Preferred networks, click Add

[image]

• Name the Network name (SSID) in accordance with what we want here such as the example I gave the name MyNet (on other computers have the same name (MyNet)). -> Click OK

• In the Wireless network key, to be more easily filled first network Authentication: Open, Data encryption required: Disable. (If you want to direct please use protection too, but you should like it first, then if you've managed to please the person who tinkers connections this option)

[image]

So that the preferred networks will show the SSID name you created with the name MyNet -> click ok to exit.

[image]

• Perform the same steps on a laptop / computer to be connected to another. (Remember the name / network name (SSID) must be equal (MyNet)).

If both computers already be set as the above steps, the next step is to go live will connect to the Network Connection, then right click on Wireless Network Connection -> select View available wireless networks.
There would appear with the name MyNet SSID, highlight it with your mouse and click the Connect button. Wait a while until the status is Connected.

[image]

• To see the success of the connections between computers, we can do a ping command to the name of the computer opponents.

- To know the name of the computer: right click on my computer -> properties -> select the Computer Name tab -> full computer name (= name of the computer)
- Open the Command prompt (start -> Click RUN -> type cmd -> click OK)
- Type namakomputerlawan ping (ping space computer name of the opponent) press enter, if successful will be no reply from the computer opponent.
- If no reply has not been successful does not mean, as it may be a function of the computer next to her for the disabled.